# i am trying to have a full page responsive image with no luck

Tags: html, css

I want to place an image with a height of 1350px and a 100% width and to be responsive I don't know what I am missing here and what should I do to make it work . I tried cover background size and contain and many other classes and styles with no luck !!  NB: the point is to force the visitor scroll down so he can view the rest of the image!

```
<style>body{background: url('./images/ddddddddd.jpg') no-repeat center fixed; width: 915px;height:1300px;}</style>
```

Comment: In your text you are writing about 100% width, in the code you have 915px width - which one is right?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly it is you want to do? If you make your image 100% width but of a fixed height it will be stretched in one direction or the other. Is that OK? I think it would help if you could show us the actual image as well as explain what you expect 'responsive' to mean if you are setting a fixed height.

Comment: i want to be able to scroll down i want to background to be full but at the same time i want to scroll down to see the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't have any element *inside*  your body, this won't work, since by default the body is only as high as its contents, and if there are no contents, it can even be 0px high. So you either have to add some contents, or apply a `height` setting to `body` in order to see *any* part of its background image. If you want it to be higher than the viewport, your height setting should be chosen accordingly, for example `height: 200vh` to make it twice as high as the viewport.

Comment: Thanks man it works plus i was adding a fixed style to the background my bad cheers bro